# Authentication base64

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-roo

I am developping an application with Spring roo.
As a first authentication test implying Spring security I used authentication against a table in my database. That work fine :

```
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" authorities-by-username-query="select username,authority from users where username=?"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Now things get a little more challenging (for me) because the password in the "real" (in the production env) user table is encrypted, I have to first use the hash function md5 and then the base64 encoding as well as iso to deal with special characters.

I have to create a custom jdbc-user-service. What would be the best practices to deal with those operations ?

Comment: Have you looked at the existing password encoder functionality that ships with Spring Security?

Comment: Yes. This is very good but unfortunately, the coding method used for existing username and password is kind of exotic and I have to build it...

Comment: Right, I get that, but if you look at the existing implementations, you should have some good pointers for how to implement this. I don't see why you would need a custom JDBC user service, a password encoder implementation wired to your user details service should work fine.

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time figuring out what your question is - do you want to know how to create a custom password encoder, or how to wire it to a standard JDBC user service, or both?

Comment: I would need both actually. You are right, my questions are no precise because I don't understand fully spring security. I have found some good resources on the password-encoder tag (using ref to a bean) but I am confused on how I can create the password encoder, how can I use the different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I managed to solve the problem with Spring security build in authentification.

I had first to set the encoding of the security-context.xml to ISO-8859-1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

then use :

```
<password-encoder hash="md5" base64="true" ></password-encoder>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is the create a custom password-encoder that will allow me more controle over the authentication process.

1. In the applicationContext-Security.xml
2. Create the custom class

   public class SnatiPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

   ```
   @Override
   public String encodePassword(String arg0, Object arg1)
           throws DataAccessException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isPasswordValid(String arg0, String arg1, Object arg2)
           throws DataAccessException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return false;
   }

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   ```

   }

What should come next ?